# Find largest set of lines which are parallel but not colinear

Tags: geometry

I have a 5 lines below with each line representing a,b,c in ax+by+c = 0

```
1 0 0
1 2 3
3 4 5
30 40 0
30 40 50
```

I want to find the largest set of non colinear parallel lines from these lines. The result in the above case will be:-

```
set of 2 lines
3 4 5
30 40 0
```

The brute force approach would be to go through all the possible combinations which would be O(n*(n+1)/2) and update the largest possible set after each iteration.

Is there any way to find the set size faster?

Comment: Why do you call them *near* colinear ?

Comment: You can normalize the coefficients and count the duplicates in a, b.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Removed near colinear, didn't know they mean something entirely different. Thanks!! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to transform the coordinates into `(angle, distance from origin)`. Finding the largest set will then be `O(nlogn)`.

Assuming that `(a,b)` are never both 0, find the distance to origin `d` using `d = c/|(a,b)|`. Then, find the angle `θ` using `θ = atan2(b,a)`. You then have a list of coordinates that looks like this:

```
[[θ0,d0],
 [θ1,d1],
...
]
```

Sort this list using `θ` as the key.

Remove all elements that you consider colinear given a threshold. Simply parse the list to check if some pairs of consecutive elements have approximately the same value. Do not forget to test the last element with the first element to account for `360° = 0°`. If you encounter a colinear pair, remove one of the element.

Using a minimum and maximum index starting at 0, increase the maximum index until the difference between the first angle (at min index) and the last angle (at max index) pass the angle tolerance that you can accept as being parallel (do not forget to consider that 359.999° is close to 0°). If the size of the set (max index - min index) is bigger than your current best set, note it as the current best. Then, increase the minimum index by one and continue increasing the maximum index until the angle difference test fail again. Continue to do so until the minimum index reaches the end of the list and do not forget to make the maximum index wrap to 0 to consider the cases close to 0° and 360°.

To make it easier to find the elements in the user provided list, you can add the original index to the transformed list, e.g., `[[θ0,d0,0],[θ1,d1,1],...]`.

Some implementation details to consider to avoid making it accidentally O(n^2): Removing an element from an contiguous array is O(n), so instead of removing colinear elements every time you encounter one, note the index in a separate list and recreate the array in a second pass. If you instead use a linked list, the min/max index should be replaced by iterators to avoid the O(n) random access using an index to access an element.